# What is guaranteed given these conditions?

Tags: functions

If $f'(0) = 0$, $f(-1) = -1$, $f(1) = 1$, then what is guaranteed to be true?

I know the answer, it's ($2$), but I am interested in knowing why this is the case, and why the other's aren't true answers.

$1$$ f(0)$ is guaranteed to be a maximum or a minimum.

$2$ There exists an $x  \in (-1,1)$ so that $f'(x) = 1$

$3$ There exists an $x  \in [-1,0]$ so that $f'(x)>0$

Which rules/theorems/logic do we apply to solve this?

Comment: Neither seems to be true...

Answer (score 0):

(2) Is not true, because $f(x)=1$ satisfies all three of your conditions, but there is no $x$ such that $f'(x) = 1$.

The same function also proves that (3) is not true

(1) is not true because of functions like $f(x)=x^3$ (which proves that $f'(0)$ can be true although $0$ is not a maxiumu of minimum.

---

After edit:

You can see that $f(x)=x^3$ shows that (1) is not correct.

You can also easily draw a curve that goes down from $(-1,-1)$ to $(0,-2)$, and only then starts curving up, so (3) isn't true euther.

To prove that (2) is correct, take a look at Lagrange's mean value theorem.

Comment: That's weird. Copied this straight off an answer sheet.... let me just reread everything, 2 sec..... EDIT: Okay, made a small mistake. f(-1) = -1.... Sorry.

Comment: @dani The way the answer is posed now, there is no answer.

Comment: @Dani I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Is not true, the first derivative rule says that when a $f'(x) = 0$ then $f(x)$ is a **local minimum, a local maximum, or a point of inflection**.  So $f(0)$ could be a point of inflection, as some one else pointed out when $f(x)=x^3$ then $f(0)$ is neither a local maximum or local minimum.

(2) Is true, given the values $f(-1)=-1$ and $f(1)=1$, and assuming the function is continuous/derivable on the interval $x \in (-1,1)$, then you know that $\frac{f'(1)-f'(-1)}{f(1)-f(-1)} = 1$, and if any part of the interval has a gradient less than one then there must be an alternate part with a gradient greater then 1, so there must be a part that is exactly 1 if the whole curve is not a straight line.

(3) Is false, if you were to sketch a graph of $f(x)$ against $x$, you have two known points $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$, but you know nothing about the points between. Statement three states that there is a positive gradient between $x=-1$ and $x=0$, ask yourself if it is possible to draw a continuous line from $(-1, -1)$ to $(1, 1)$ with no positive gradient between $x=-1$ and $x=0$, and a zero gradient at $x=0$, this line would pass through the points you have defined and the points in the derivative you have defined, but not meet condition 3.